# Users with non-verified emails can see the dashboard in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel-10

I have a fresh new Laravel 10 application with the breeze starter kit for security https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits.

When I registered the first user in this application, the browser instantly displays the "/dashboard" with the text "You are logged in", although the email address of this user has not yet been verified. I. e. in MySQL the column "email_verified_at" equals to NULL.

This seems to be wrong as the route is protected by this

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');
```

Thus, the "/dashboard" should only be visible for a user with a verified email address, but also a non-verified user has access.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The model for the user ("app/models/user.php") needs to include

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
```

and the class needs to implement accordingly

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail {
...
}
```